# What does it mean to identify isomorphic objects and when is it ok to do so?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, terminology, definition

I thought that an identification of isomorphic objects is done to simplify notation. If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and $\varphi:V \to W$ is an isomorphism, we can translate statements about $V$ to statements about $W$ by using $\varphi$. This can simplify notation, when working with compositions or equivalence classes. However, this doesn't seem to be all there is, since a quick research leads to various examples of when it is bad to identify isomorphic objects, such as a vector space with its dual. If $V,W$ are n $n$-dimensional vector spaces, there is an isomorphism $V \cong W$ by choosing a basis. This is called "non-canonical", since it involves a choice - a different basis gives different isomorphisms. As for simplifying notation, I don't see why this would cause a problem. If we choose a bases of the spaces and let $\varphi$ be the respective isomorphism, then we should be able to simplify notation using $\varphi$. So since this appears to cause problems, there has to be more to it than I initially thought. This leads to the following questions.

$(1)$ What does it mean to identify isomorphic objects?

$(2)$ What can go wrong when identifying two isomorphic objects that are not canonically isomorphic?

$(3)$ Is it always safe to identify canonically isomorphic objects? If so, why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142374/discussion-on-question-by-user1578232-what-does-it-mean-to-identify-isomorphic-o).

Comment: I once had been asked to review a manscript where the "proofs" were based on the following argument for isomorphic (in the category of topological spaces one rather says homeomorphic) intervals: $[a,b]\cong [c,d]$, hence $[a,b]\cap [0,1] \cong [c,d]\cap [0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

In the category **Grp** of groups,  usually you can forget about the distinction between isomorphic ones, for instance $S_3\cong D_3$, or $V_4\cong \Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$, but certainly not always.

For instance,  $n\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z$, but if you identify them and take a quotient,  you would get $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z\cong \{e\}.$

Also,  when you consider subgroups of a given group,  you generally don't want to identify isomorphic groups.   For instance,  $S_4$ has four Klein four subgroups.   But only one is normal.

Or, Sylow subgroups are of course isomorphic,  but when there's more than one it can be important to distinguish between them.

In general,  the whole subgroup lattice of a group is grounded in distinguishing between all the different,  but some possibly isomorphic, subgroups.

Comment: An abstraction of almost all these points is that it's usually wrong to think of a subgroup of a given group as an object of $\mathbf{Grp}$: it's more often an object of the slice category $\mathbf{Grp}/B$ for some $B$ (if you need the subgroup up to equality), or a morphism in the 2-category of groups (if you need it up to conjugacy.) Objects being isomorphic doesn't imply isomorphism for arrows involving them.